# return in a function does not give any resuls

Tags: python, function

```
def fun(num1,num2):
    def deviders(num):
        devider_list = []
        while num % 2 == 0 and num > 0:
            devider_list.append(2)
            break
        while num % 3 == 0 and num > 0:
            devider_list.append(3)
        while num % 5 == 0 and num > 0:
            devider_list.append(5)
        while num % 7 == 0 and num > 0:
            devider_list.append(7)
        return devider_list()
    list_num1 = deviders(num1)
    list_num2 = deviders(num2)

    return list_num1,list_num2
raw_input4 = 4
raw_input5 = 6
print (fun(raw_input4,raw_input5))
```

when i run the program nothing gets executed.i dont see why it doesnt return  anithing.any idea why?

Comment: What debugging have you done? It should give "results"... Specifically, this should raise an exception since lists are not callable at `return devider_list() ` (assuming the code reaches there and you don't have an infinite loop, e.g. `while 6 % 3 == 0` has no `break`)

Comment: When the second number (6) goes through `deviders`, the second test (`num % 3 == 0 and num > 0`) is always True and the code loops infinitely

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of issues here...

1. You have multiple while loops which do not modify the value of num. Only the first loop actually breaks out if the conditions are met. Modify these to either modify the value of num so it will eventually leave the loop or change the code so you have if statements instead of while loops. Otherwise your application will run infinitely in the while loops without any way of leaving them.
2. You're calling decoder_list() in the return statement.